# Slow query to fill down empty cells with values from a previous non-empty row

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, subquery

I got this query to fill down empty cells with values from a previous non-empty row but it's taking so long (there are almost 100.000 records).

Hope you can help me with a faster query to achieve this .

These are all the dll with a sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS(
     id_num int IDENTITY(1,1),[Provider] varchar(59), [Location] varchar(104),last_update datetime2, [Total_Charge] money
      );
INSERT INTO #TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS
    ([Provider], [Location],[last_update],[Total_Charge])
VALUES
    ('Vimalkumar Veerappan', 'Arizona Heart Specialists',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,100.0),
    (' ', 'Banner Boswell Medical Center - Inpatient',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,102.0),
    (' ', 'Arizona Heart Specialists WEST',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,800.0),
   ('Akash Makkar', 'Arizona Heart Specialists WEST',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,500.0),
  (' ', 'Pinnacle Vein & Vascular Center Sun City',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,500.0),
  (' ', 'Abrazo Arizona Heart Hospital - Outpatient',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,60.0),
  (' ', 'Banner Boswell Medical Center - Inpatient',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,60.0),
  (' ', 'Banner Del E Webb Medical Center - Inpatient',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,10.0)
select id_num,[Provider],[Location],[Total_Charge],[last_update]
from #TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS where IsNull([Provider], '') <> ''
union
select y.id_num, x.[Provider], y.[Location],y.[Total_Charge],y.[last_update]
from #TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS as x
join(
select t1.id_num,max(t2.id_num) as MaxID, t1.[Location],t1.[Total_Charge],t1.[last_update]
from (select * from #TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS where IsNull([Provider], '') = '') as t1
join (select * from #TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS where IsNull([Provider], '') <> '') as t2 on t1.id_num > t2.id_num
group by t1.id_num,  t1.[Location],t1.[Total_Charge],t1.[last_update]
)as y on x.id_num = y.MaxID order by id_num;
```

Comment: Performance related questions require an execution plan, using Paste The Plan.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways of doing this:

Old skool:

```sql
SELECT  id_num
,   CASE WHEN provider = '' THEN (SELECT    TOP 1 Provider FROM #TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS tt WHERE   tt.id_num < t.id_num AND Provider <> '' ORDER BY id_num DESC) ELSE provider END
,   location, last_update, Total_Charge
FROM    #TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS t
```

This fetches the last non-empty provider from previous rows if current one is  empty. Downside is extra join.

New hotness:

```sql
SELECT  id_num
,   CASE 
        WHEN provider = '' THEN STUFF(MAX(RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000000',id_num), 10) + CASE WHEN Provider <> '' THEN Provider END) OVER(ORDER BY id_num), 1, 10, '')
        ELSE provider END
,   location, last_update, Total_Charge
FROM    #TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS t
```

I don't know the name of this technique but what it does is creates a single frame of combination of id_num + provider, like: 0000000001Vimalkumar Veerappan. Where provider is empty, we change it to NULL, so value becomes NULL.

By taking `MAX(...) OVER (ORDER BY id_num)` call, we fetch the last value in that frame. Then, by doing `STUFF(...)` we remove the 0000000001 part, and what's left is what we need.

This technique enables a single windowed call, which might generate best performance, downside is somewhat obscure code.

Comment: Love the performance of that siggemanne ! I was testing my rather old fashioned method and it was taking 3 mins to run over 100,000 rows on a small docker container, so the actual time is not too important, but running this version on the same docker container took 2 seconds ! Just need to wrap my head around it now :)

Answer (score 0):

We won't be able to tell what's going on without a plan (as Dale suggests).
In the mean time, maybe this will be a little better:

```
SELECT x.id_num, COALESCE(NULLIF(x.Provider,' '),y.provider) AS [Provider], x.Location, x.last_update, x.Total_Charge
  FROM @TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS x
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(id_num) AS mid_num FROM @TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS y WHERE y.id_num < x.id_num AND y.[Provider] IS NOT NULL AND y.Provider <> ' ' AND x.Provider = '') a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS y
      ON a.mid_num = y.id_num;
```

| id_num | Provider | Location | last_update | Total_Charge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vimalkumar Veerappan | Arizona Heart Specialists | 2023-10-04 15:55:59.6833333 | 100.00 |
| 2 | Vimalkumar Veerappan | Banner Boswell Medical Center - Inpatient | 2023-10-04 15:55:59.6833333 | 102.00 |
| 3 | Vimalkumar Veerappan | Arizona Heart Specialists WEST | 2023-10-04 15:55:59.6833333 | 800.00 |
| 4 | Akash Makkar | Arizona Heart Specialists WEST | 2023-10-04 15:55:59.6833333 | 500.00 |
| 5 | Akash Makkar | Pinnacle Vein & Vascular Center Sun City | 2023-10-04 15:55:59.6833333 | 500.00 |
| 6 | Akash Makkar | Abrazo Arizona Heart Hospital - Outpatient | 2023-10-04 15:55:59.6833333 | 60.00 |
| 7 | Akash Makkar | Banner Boswell Medical Center - Inpatient | 2023-10-04 15:55:59.6833333 | 60.00 |
| 8 | Akash Makkar | Banner Del E Webb Medical Center - Inpatient | 2023-10-04 15:55:59.6833333 | 10.00 |

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much. I tested all your solutions and it seems that the fastest one was with LAG function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure or SQL Server 2022, you can just use [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with `IGNORE NULLS`

This avoids JOINS correlated subqueries, etc, etc, and only scans the table once.

```
SELECT
  *,
  LAG(
    NULLIF(Provider, ' '),
    0
  )
    IGNORE NULLS
    OVER (
      ORDER BY id_num
    )
FROM
  #TEST_INSURANCE_PAYMENTS
```

| id_num | Provider | Location | last_update | Total_Charge | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vimalkumar Veerappan | Arizona Heart Specialists | 2023-10-04 22:41:21.590 | 100.0000 | Vimalkumar Veerappan |
| 2 |  | Banner Boswell Medical Center - Inpatient | 2023-10-04 22:41:21.590 | 102.0000 | Vimalkumar Veerappan |
| 3 |  | Arizona Heart Specialists WEST | 2023-10-04 22:41:21.590 | 800.0000 | Vimalkumar Veerappan |
| 4 | Akash Makkar | Arizona Heart Specialists WEST | 2023-10-04 22:41:21.590 | 500.0000 | Akash Makkar |
| 5 |  | Pinnacle Vein & Vascular Center Sun City | 2023-10-04 22:41:21.590 | 500.0000 | Akash Makkar |
| 6 |  | Abrazo Arizona Heart Hospital - Outpatient | 2023-10-04 22:41:21.590 | 60.0000 | Akash Makkar |
| 7 |  | Banner Boswell Medical Center - Inpatient | 2023-10-04 22:41:21.590 | 60.0000 | Akash Makkar |
| 8 |  | Banner Del E Webb Medical Center - Inpatient | 2023-10-04 22:41:21.590 | 10.0000 | Akash Makkar |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o2Gccq4i)